# How to Avoid "Select" to optimize the following code

Tags: excel, offset

How would you optimize the following code :

```
Sheet.Activate
Sheet.Cells(i,j).EntireRow.Select
selection.Copy
selection.Offset(1).Insert
```

I am particularly bogged with the last line
Thanks

Comment: `Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i + 1)`  Obligatory link:  [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Bravo and Merci !